# beginner SQL conditional INSERT INTO question

Tags: mysql, insert

Here's a pseudo-table:

```
Table: people
    name : varchar
    is_married : varchar
```

I have a php variable $selected_individual whose is_married status I need to update. I'm stuck after

```
SELECT * from people
WHERE name = '$selected_individual'
```

How do I update his is_married status?

This maybe related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/554205/with-mysql-how-do-i-insert-into-a-table-on-condition-that-the-value-does-not-exi) but nested queries and JOIN are way to advanced for me to get my head around at this point (I'll look into them after some much needed sleep).

edit: for example in this query,

```
INSERT INTO x_table(instance, user, item) 
    SELECT 919191, 123, 456
        FROM dual
        WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM x_table
                             WHERE user = 123 
                               AND item = 456)
```

I can't seem to figure where can I plug in my 'yes' value myself for is_married column. (or where do I put VALUES ('yes') in there?)

Comment: I don't see any mention of anything conditional here.  Are you meaning to say that the "selected_individual" may or may not exist in the table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
update people set is_married = 'Y' where name = '$selected_individual';
```

Comment: wow that is... ok.. so I need to use 'update' to update existing values and not 'insert'. *face-palm*

Answer (score 1):

While **Paul Tomblin** has provided a direct answer, I'd like to add the following recommendation and *best practices*:

- Read a [General Introduction to SQL](http://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=introduction%20to%20sql&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8)
- [Use a primary key](http://blogs.oracle.com/carriergrademysql/entry/mysql_cluster_basics_why_using)
- Prevent [SQL Injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php)

Comment: thanks for the links! I already did spend last couple hours reading up all the basics. I'll look more into that Injection thing in the morning. never would've thought you could gain admin access by simply changing your password. o_o