# Check if the value exist in another table and then insert

Tags: php, mysql, insert

I'm working on a form in PHP that inserts data to MySQL, but before the data is inserted there is a field that must be checked in another table before inserting. If this value exist in the other table, then the data is inserted in the main table, if not, then data is not inserted.

Here is my code to insert the data:

```
$host = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$db_name = "forms";
$tbl_name = "table1";

mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password") or die("cannot connect");
mysql_select_db("$db_name") or die("cannot select DB");

$nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
$apellido = $_POST['apellido'];
$cedula = $_POST['cedula'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$telefono = $_POST['telefono'];
$establecimiento = $_POST['establecimiento'];
$codigo = $_POST['codigo'];

$sql = " INSERT INTO $tbl_name(Nombre, Apellido, Cedula, Email, Telefono, Establecimiento, Codigo)VALUES('$nombre', '$apellido', '$cedula', '$email', '$telefono', '$establecimiento', '$codigo')";

$result = mysql_query($sql);

if ($result) {
    echo "Your data was sent";
} else {
    echo "You inserted a wrong code";
}

?>

<?php
// close connection 
mysql_close();
?>
```

So, what I need is to check the value $codigo in table2, if exists, then insert $codigo in table1 with the other values. This is where I'm stuck.

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/554205/with-mysql-how-do-i-insert-into-a-table-on-condition-that-the-value-does-not-ex?rq=1

Comment: Another thing is you should not be using mysql_* functions. Use something like mysqli_* or PDO. The way you are coding now is open for SQL injection making your code a huge security risk. A quick google search will point you in the right direction for those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you really need to do is this.

```
// Check if Codigo already exists in table2
$codigo = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['codigo']);
$result = mysql_query("SELECT Codigo FROM table2 WHERE Codigo = '$codigo'");

if (!mysql_num_rows($result)) {

    // Go ahead and insert everything in table1
    $data = array(
        'Nombre' => $_POST['Nombre'],
        'Apellido' => $_POST['apellido'],
        'Cedula' => $_POST['cedula'],
        'Email' => $_POST['email'],
        'Telefono' => $_POST['telefono'],
        'Establecimiento' => $_POST['establecimiento'],
        'Codigo' => $_POST['codigo']
    );

    // Make sure all the data is safe for entry into the database
    foreach ($data as $key => $val) {
        $data[$key] = "'" . mysql_real_escape_string($val) . "'";
    }

    $fields = implode(', ', array_keys($data));
    $values = implode(', ', array_values($data));

    $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO table1 ($fields) VALUES ($values)");

    echo 'Your data was sent';

} else {
    echo 'Codigo already exists in table2';
}
```

But please note there are many ways of doing this that are far better and more efficient.  For one, I would recommend you use PHP's mysqli functions rather than the deprecated mysql ones (http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)

More importantly, you don't look like you're protecting your queries against SQL injection at all.  Please read up on this, but it's usually just a need for real_escape_string() on any value you are inserting into a SQL query.

Comment: Thank you for your response. This seems more close to what i want, but when i tested what it does is to insert 'Codigo' if it does not find it in table2. What I want is the other way around: to insert 'Codigo' in table1 if it finds it in table2.

Comment: Oops, sorry.  Yes, at this line `if (!mysql_num_rows($result)) {
` remove the `!` to reverse the polarity of the condition.

Answer (score 0):

Simply do a SELECT query on the other table with the data you are checking for and then if mysql_num_rows() > 0 you do an insert. Something like below

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM otherTable WHERE infoIsSame";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    $sql=" INSERT INTO $tbl_name(Nombre, Apellido, Cedula, Email, Telefono, Establecimiento, Codigo)VALUES('$nombre', '$apellido', '$cedula', '$email', '$telefono', '$establecimiento', '$codigo')";

    $result=mysql_query($sql);

    if($result){
        echo "Your data was sent";
    }else {
        echo "You inserted a wrong code";
    }
}else{
    echo "Not present in Other database";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to let the INSERT statement do the check for you:

```
INSERT INTO $tbl_name (Nombre, Apellido, Cedula, Email, Telefono, Establecimiento, Codigo)
SELECT '$nombre', '$apellido', '$cedula', '$email', '$telefono', '$establecimiento', '$codigo'
  FROM table2
 WHERE table2.Codigo = '$codigo'
 LIMIT 1
```

Then check the number of rows inserted `mysql_affected_rows()` to determine whether a row was inserted or not. This fewer round trips to the database, for the "normative" case where you expect a row to be inserted.

---

**NOTE:** avoid using mysql_ functions and use mysqli_ or PDO instead.